# Guidelines and Best Practice: Prep to Temporarily Shutting Down an Active Directory Domain Controller

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller

1 AD domain. 3 total Domain controllers, all on 2008 R2

The primary DC (with FSMO roles) is being moved to a new office and it will be offline for a maximum of 3 days. 
This DC also serves DNS but the other DC also has that role.

I am planning to migrate the FSMO roles to secondary server, and then just simply power this one down and boot it back up at the new site. Currently not planning on taking any other steps to prep for this server move.

Once the new office is ready and the DC is booted back up, I plan to allow synchronization from the other controllers, and then re-apply the FSMO roles back to it.

**My question is** -- Is my method ok? Is there any other steps I need to take to plan for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your environment is healthy and properly redundant as you say, this is fine.

Comment: Due to your rep and credentials, I'm confident in your advice and thanks for the input. Marking this as the answer.